# RasiePropertyChanged is not working, If BindableBase is indirectly inherited. OneWay mode

Tags: mvvm, prism, bindable

My viewmodel is indirectly inherited from BindableBase class, and when I change a property in viewmodel, it doesn't update the UI. When I directly inherit it from BindableBase class then it updates the UI.
This is case with "OneWay" mode. If I use "TwoWay" mode, it works fine in both cases. Can anybody please help me with possible reasons of this issue.

Comment: Code? Xaml? Any details?

Comment: If you post the view model code it would be helpful, otherwise we are just guessing

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the INotifyPropertyChanged interface explicitly to every class in the chain of inheritance to see if it helps.

```
DerivedClassA: BindableBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 What you already had
}


DerivedClassB: DerivedClassA, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
 What you already had
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. I have this working just fine but I use MVM-Light instead of Prism.